# ScrollViewer in Grid

Tags: wpf, prism, scrollviewer

I have the following piece of xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static local:RegionNames.MainMenuRegion}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

If I set VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Visible everything works fine. If I set it to Auto the ScrollBar is never displayed (even when it would be needed).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Your containing panel is unconstrained - particularly, you've set `Grid.Row=1` to have a height of `*`, which means "use all the available space". So your panel just grows instead of showing the ScrollViewer.

Try setting it to a constrained height, and the ScrollViewer should appear when the MenuItems in your main menu are too many.

Comment: It's the other way around, `*` will restrict it and `Auto` lets it have whatever space it desires. So the problem is the Column and not the Row :)

Comment: If the panel is bigger than the content, the content is allowed to grow until it fills the panel - that's what I meant. It restricts it, but only to the maximum size. It says "use all the available space" rather than "grow if you need to" but that still may be causing it. I don't think the column definitions could really affect the *vertical* scrollbar.

Comment: Just try the samplecode. Suppose the content has a Width of 2000 and the Column has Width set to `Auto`, you would never be able to see the `ScrollViewer` since it would be way of screen. Then again, the problem might be that it's to small.. I might have missunderstood the problem

Comment: Go submit that as an answer; you're possibly right and should get credit :)

Comment: But I see the scrollbar if I set VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible". Everything works just fine in this case. If Lunivore would be correct that the the row height of * is the problem it would also not display in that case, or am I missunderstanding something? The grid by the way is the direct child of a window. So "all available space" is, as i understand, the content area of the window an not more.

Comment: This worked for me. My problem was that I had set the Height and Width of the WrapPanel within the ScrollViewer. Once I moved these two constraints to the ScrollViewer everything worked well. I did also have to set my WrapPanel Width to Auto, and Height to the height of ScrollViewer, and set Orientation to Vertical, as I want that to be fixed and the WrapPanel only to scroll right and left.